# Как сделать на сайте редирект на определённую страницу учитывая источник перехода?

Tags: php, javascript, redirect

Например, ссылка site.ru в профиле инстаграм редиректилась на site.ru/instagram,  соответственно site.ru в профиле facebook вела на site.ru/facebook. Во всех остальных случаях вела как есть - на главную.

Answer (score 1):

Проверять регулярным выражением $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'].

Что-то вроде:

```
if (preg_match("www.facebook.com", $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])) {
  header('Location: http://site.ru/facebook/');
} else if (preg_match("www.instagram.com", $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])) {
  header('Location: http://site.ru/instagram/');
} else header('Location: http://site.ru/');
```

Comment: спасибо. но не пашет :( ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS  Насколько я изучил вопрос при редиректе реферер остается первоначальный поэтому такая беда. Но это можно было бы наверное решить - проверяя лишь главную страницу. Однако, переход не из этих соц. сетей точно так же приводит к этой ошибке. Не пойму почему... Возможно я не правильно его устанавливаю. CMS WP - вставлял в function.php